# java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: target - exception when initiating a flow from the command shell [errorCode=g3v6fv]

Tags: corda

When initiating a flow from the command shell I get the following exception:

[ERROR] 2019-04-10T15:02:07,809Z [pool-8-thread-2] command.CRaSHSession.execute - Error while evaluating request 'flow start IOUFlowInitiator' flow start IOUFlowInitiator: exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: target [errorCode=g3v6fv, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0/g3v6fv]
net.corda.core.CordaRuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: target

"target" is not the name of any of the arguments in my flow.

There is no further information in the log.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem was with my build of OpenJDK.  I was using the OpenJ9 variant of OpenJDK 8.  Switching to the HotSpot variant resolved the problem.